# Express app with Cloud Function - no such file or directory

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to serve my react project with a cloud function. But with the following code I get the error 500 with:

> server error [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/build/index.html']

How can I access the hosting folder?

this is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs").promises;

const app = express();

app.get("/*", async (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./build", "index.html");
  try {
    let data = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
    data = data
      .replace(/__TITLE__/g, "Gnossi Wohnig")
      .replace(/__THUMB__/g, "")
      .replace(/__DESCRIPTION__/g, "Genossenschaftswohnung in Zürich finden");
    res.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")));

exports.webApi = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The build folder needs to be copied into the functions folder. Putting the following into the package.json solved the problem:

```
    "build": "react-scripts build && cp -r build functions",
```